# How to find file location of running VBScript in background?

Tags: python, batch-file, vbscript, taskmanager

I do **penetration testing** a lot all the day;
I taken a **python script from github** and now I **forgot** its name;
I ran it after it got **hidden** to my system anywhere;
Everytime I starts my system an cmd opens;
Then **VB SCRIPT** message popups and disturbs me a lot that I am tired.
Screenshot:
[image]

And when I open **task manager**,
and click open file location,
It takes me to `C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe`
Not to file location from where it was being launched.
[image]

[image]

I accept any type of answer that will solve my problem,
Any type means **any type** (e.g programmatic,manual,etc).

Comment: There is no point showing the summary tab in Task Manager - show the DETAILS TAB.

Comment: @Mark https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMGjz.png

Comment: @MuhammadAli May be the main script is loacted on your Run registry and we don't know if a vbscript or a batch file launch those child scripts ? Can you confirm my suggestion ?

Comment: @Hackoo Yeah it can be, As I mentioned that at startup cmd opens, And I think it lauches all these vbscripts. And I don't know how can I investigate it.

Comment: @MuhammadAli I will try to post you another answer for the startup locations on registry but with a batch script !

Comment: @Hackoo Thanks, you are so kind.

Comment: Have you checked the `Startup` tab in Task Manager to see if it's shown there? Just look through the list and investigate anything you don't recognise. If not shown right-click on the columns to show both `Startup type` and `Command line` columns which allow you to pinpoint where the process is running from `Registry`, `Folder` etc and what command is running.

Comment: This does not require a script to investigate, it's basic Operating System knowledge and understanding the locations where applications can be executed automatically *(Task Scheduler, Registry, Startup folder etc)*.

Answer (score 4):

You should extract their command line to find their locations !

Just copy and paste this code below as ***Get_CommandLine_Process.bat*** and execute it by double click and it will extract their paths in order to explore them with your windows explorer.

```dos
@echo off
Title Extract CommandLine Of Running Processes by Hackoo 2020
Mode 100,30 & color 0A
Set "ProcessName=wscript.exe"
Set "TmpFile=%~n0_Abs_cmdline.txt"
Set "LogFile=%~n0_cmdline.txt
If Exist "%TmpFile%" Del "%TmpFile%"
If Exist "%LogFile%" Del "%LogFile%"
Set "ProcessCmd="
Set /a "Count=0"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@For /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%P in ('wmic process where caption^="%ProcessName%" get commandline /format:list ^| find /I "%ProcessName%" 2^>nul') do (
        Set /a Count+=1
        Set "ProcessCmd[!Count!]=%%P"
)
@for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
        echo !ProcessCmd[%%i]!>con
        echo !ProcessCmd[%%i]! >> "%TmpFile%"
)
Timeout /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
If exist "%TmpFile%" Call :Extract "%TmpFile%" "%LogFile%"
@For /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%LogFile%"') do (
    Explorer /n, /select, %%a
)
REM If exist "%LogFile%" Start "" "%LogFile%" & Exit
pause & Exit
::********************************************************************************************************
:Extract <InputData> <OutPutData>
(
echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
echo Data = Extract(Data,"(^?^!.*(\x22\w^)^)\b.*(\w^).*(\.ps1^|\.hta^|\.vbs^|\.vbe^|\.cmd^|\.bat^|\.lnk^)"^)
echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Data
echo '************************************************
echo Function Extract(Data,Pattern^)
echo    Dim oRE,oMatches,Match,Line
echo    set oRE = New RegExp
echo    oRE.IgnoreCase = True
echo    oRE.Global = True
echo    oRE.Pattern = Pattern
echo    set oMatches = oRE.Execute(Data^)
echo    If not isEmpty(oMatches^) then
echo        For Each Match in oMatches  
echo            Line = Line ^& chr(34^) ^& Trim(Match.Value^) ^& chr(34^) ^& vbcrlf
echo        Next
echo        Extract = Line 
echo    End if
echo End Function
echo '************************************************
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" < "%~1" > "%~2"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
exit /b
::****************************************************
```

---

***EDIT :*** Here is another code in pure vbscript : ***WScript_Explorer_Location.vbs***

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,Process,ColProcess
Title = "Find file location of running VBScript in background"
ColProcess = Find_Location("wscript.exe")
For Each Process in ColProcess
    MsgBox Process,vbInformation,Title
    Explorer(Process)
Next
'-------------------------------------------------
Sub Explorer(File)
    Dim ws
    Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    ws.run "Explorer /n,/select,"& File &""
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------
Function Find_Location(MyProcess)
    Dim colItems,objItem,CmdLine,ArrProcess
    ArrProcess = Array()
    Set colItems = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process " _
    & "Where Name like '%"& MyProcess &"%' AND NOT commandline like '%" & wsh.scriptname & "%'",,48)
    For Each objItem in colItems
        If objItem.CommandLine <> "" Then
            CmdLine = Extract(objItem.CommandLine,"(?!.*(\x22\w))\b.*(\w).*(\.ps1|\.hta|\.vbs|\.vbe|\.cmd|\.bat|\.lnk)")
            ReDim Preserve ArrProcess(UBound(ArrProcess)+1)
            ArrProcess(UBound(ArrProcess))= CmdLine
        End If
    Next
    Find_Location = ArrProcess
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------
Function Extract(Data,Pattern)
    Dim oRE,oMatches,Match,Line
    set oRE = New RegExp
    oRE.IgnoreCase = True
    oRE.Global = True
    oRE.Pattern = Pattern
    set oMatches = oRE.Execute(Data)
    If not isEmpty(oMatches) then
        For Each Match in oMatches  
            Line = Line & chr(34) & Trim(Match.Value) & chr(34) & vbcrlf
        Next
        Extract = Line 
    End if
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------
```

---

If you want to use the same vbscript to find others process running like `cscript.exe`, `mshta.exe`, `cmd.exe`, in the background in order to explore their locations, just put them into an array like that : `ArrayProcesses = Array("wscript.exe","cscript.exe","mshta.exe","cmd.exe")`

And call them like that :

```
For Each ProcessItem In ArrayProcesses
ColProcesses = Find_Location(ProcessItem)
    For Each Process in ColProcesses
        MsgBox Process,vbInformation,Title
        Explorer(Process)
    Next
Next
```

---

The main vbscript can be written like this : ***Find_Explore_Process.vbs***

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,ArrayProcesses,ProcessItem,ColProcesses,Process
Title = "Find file location of running Processes in background"
ArrayProcesses = Array("wscript.exe","cscript.exe","mshta.exe","cmd.exe")
For Each ProcessItem In ArrayProcesses
ColProcesses = Find_Location(ProcessItem)
    For Each Process in ColProcesses
        MsgBox Process,vbInformation,Title
        Explorer(Process)
    Next
Next
'-------------------------------------------------
Sub Explorer(File)
    Dim ws
    Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    ws.run "Explorer /n,/select,"& File &""
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------
Function Find_Location(MyProcess)
    Dim colItems,objItem,CmdLine,ArrProcess
    ArrProcess = Array()
    Set colItems = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process " _
    & "Where Name like '%"& MyProcess &"%' AND NOT commandline like '%" & wsh.scriptname & "%'",,48)
    For Each objItem in colItems
        If objItem.CommandLine <> "" Then
            CmdLine = Extract(objItem.CommandLine,"(?!.*(\x22\w))\b.*(\w).*(\.ps1|\.hta|\.vbs|\.vbe|\.cmd|\.bat|\.lnk)")
            ReDim Preserve ArrProcess(UBound(ArrProcess)+1)
            ArrProcess(UBound(ArrProcess))= CmdLine
        End If
    Next
    Find_Location = ArrProcess
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------
Function Extract(Data,Pattern)
    Dim oRE,oMatches,Match,Line
    set oRE = New RegExp
    oRE.IgnoreCase = True
    oRE.Global = True
    oRE.Pattern = Pattern
    set oMatches = oRE.Execute(Data)
    If not isEmpty(oMatches) then
        For Each Match in oMatches  
            Line = Line & chr(34) & Trim(Match.Value) & chr(34) & vbcrlf
        Next
        Extract = Line 
    End if
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------
```

---

Refer to your edit and your comment, i come with another batch script named as : ***Scan_Registry_Run_Keys.bat*** in order to scan your registry run keys and extract their paths

```
@echo off
REM Scan_Registry_Run_Keys.bat to get info about your running keys on the registry
REM And extract all their executables paths
Title Scanning Registry Run Keys by Hackoo 2020
Mode con cols=100 lines=5 & color 9E
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
Set "TmpFile=%Temp%\TmpFile.txt"
Set "OutPutFile=%~dp0Reg_Paths_EXE.txt"
Set "Files_List2Upload=%~dp0FilesList2Upload.txt"
Set "All_Users=%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
Set "Current_User=%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

Set Keys=^
^ "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" ^
^ "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"

If Exist "%TmpFile%" Del "%TmpFile%"
If Exist "%OutPutFile%" Del "%OutPutFile%"
If Exist "%Files_List2Upload%" Del "%Files_List2Upload%"

For %%K in (%Keys%) Do (  
   cls
   echo;
   Echo             ***************************** Scanning in progress *****************************
   Echo             %%K
   Echo             ********************************************************************************
   Timeout /T 2 /Nobreak>nul
   reg query "%%~K" /s >> "%TmpFile%"
)

(
    Dir /b /s "%All_Users%"
    Dir /b /s "%Current_User%"
)>> "%TmpFile%"

Call :Extract "%TmpFile%" "%OutPutFile%"
If Exist "%TmpFile%" Start "" "%TmpFile%"

For /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%OutPutFile%"') do (
    echo "%%~a">>"%Files_List2Upload%"
)

If Exist "%OutPutFile%" Del "%OutPutFile%"
Start "" "%Files_List2Upload%"
Exit
::****************************************************
:Extract <InputData> <OutPutData>
(
echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
echo Data = Extract(Data,"(^?^!.*(REG_SZ^|REG_EXPAND_SZ^)^)\b.*(\w^).*(\.exe""^|\.exe^|\.vbs^|\.vbe^|\.cmd^|\.bat^|\.lnk^)"^)
echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Data
echo '************************************************
echo Function Extract(Data,Pattern^)
echo    Dim oRE,oMatches,Match,Line
echo    set oRE = New RegExp
echo    oRE.IgnoreCase = True
echo    oRE.Global = True
echo    oRE.Pattern = Pattern
echo    set oMatches = oRE.Execute(Data^)
echo    If not isEmpty(oMatches^) then
echo        For Each Match in oMatches   
echo            Line = Line ^& Trim(Match.Value^) ^& vbcrlf
echo        Next
echo        Extract = Line
echo    End if 
echo End Function
echo '************************************************
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" < "%~1" > "%~2"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
exit /b
::****************************************************
:ExtractTarget <Link>
(
    echo set Ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
    echo set Lnk = Ws.Createshortcut(WScript.Arguments(0^)^)
    echo WScript.Echo Lnk.TargetPath
)>Tmp.vbs
cscript //nologo Tmp.vbs "%~1" & Del Tmp.vbs
Exit /b
::****************************************************
```

Comment: Lets suppose **abc.vbs** is running in **background**.
**abc.vbs** also runs other scripts like **xyz1.vbs, xyz2.vbs, xyz3.vbs**,
Your scripts will tell the location of **xyz1.vbs, xyz2.vbs, xyz3.vbs**,
Not the file location of **abc.vbs**.

Comment: @MuhammadAli Check my last edit and tell me the result ! You can add the batch tag too if this works fine on your side !

Comment: This is overkill and no different to what the `Startup` tab in Task Manager shows.

Comment: @MuhammadAli This wouldn't solve the problem, they want to know what is trying to execute the scripts automatically at startup. The scripts themselves don't exist anymore but the entry to run them automatically does.

Comment: @Lankymart task manager startup tab is empty, I tried many things but didn't worked for me. Background Virus is launching Vb script using `C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe`. But **wscript.exe** won't tell you parent app from where it was launched. Thats the problem.

Comment: @MuhammadAli I recommend you [Emsisoft HiJackFree](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/emsisoft_hijackfree.html) is a detailed system analysis tool which helps advanced users to detect and remove all types of HiJackers, Spyware, Adware, Trojans and Worms.

Comment: @Hackoo I have eset antivirus installed, and even tried Emsisoft HiJackFree, But these both didn't worked for me, I `C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe` moved to other location, now it doesn't shows me these messages. But I don't think this is an good idea.

Comment: @Muhammad Ali of course this is a very bad idea, you should restore it and search the location of this entry in your registry with msconfig or other third party tools

Comment: @Hackoo I noticed some things in **Emsisoft HiJackFree** in tricky startup folder, I want to delete it but it is not deleted. View screenshot https://i.ibb.co/SPF0Z95/Capture.png

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Set Wsh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
script_name = Wscript.ScriptFullName
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set File = FSO.GetFile(script_name)
Folder = FSO.GetParentFolderName(File) 
strPath = "explorer.exe /e," & Folder
Wsh.Run strPath
```

This will open the parent folder of currently running script.

If you want this for another script, then replace Wscript.ScriptFullName with another script's name.

---

Or,

Open Task Manager and go to Details tab. If a VBScript is running, the process wscript.exe or cscript.exe would appear in the list.

Right-click on the column header and enable "Command Line". This should tell you which script file is being executed.

Comment: Nahi Sir aap samajhe nahi,
I want to investigate that vbscript and close it from running again,
I didn't created that VBS so I don't know from where it is executed,
So I want to know its file location.
And you about taskbar command line,
I got this `cscript.exe C:/python37/shoot.vbs`,
And that path doesn't exists.

Comment: Aap dekh rahe hai us `path` me backslash ki jagha pe slash hai. Isi liey woh `path` galat hai. You are seeing that there is slashes in the path which is Linux syntax. In Windows path there are backslashes(\) so the correct path will be `C:\python37\shoot.vbs`.

Comment: Baat to aap ki theek hai, But both these paths doesn't exists using forward or back slash.